# how to display image in html page using angular js?

Tags: html, angularjs, mongodb

I already know how to save images in mongodb using angularjs and java to save it in my mongodb, it is working fine. and getting corresponding id also

I need to get the saved image from mongodb and display it in an html page using AngularJS.

This is my controller for getting image

```
@GET
@Path("/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response getById(@PathParam("id") String id) throws IOException
{
    Response response = null;
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    DB mongoDB = mongoClient.getDB("sampleDB");
    DBCollection collection = mongoDB.getCollection("filestore");
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    ObjectId oid = new ObjectId(id);
    query.put("_id", oid);
    GridFS fileStore = new GridFS(mongoDB, "filestore");
    GridFSDBFile gridFile = fileStore.findOne(query);
    InputStream in = gridFile.getInputStream();
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int data = in.read();
    while (data >= 0)
    {
    out.write((char) data);
    data = in.read();
    }
    out.flush();
    ResponseBuilder builder = Response.ok(out.toByteArray());
    builder.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=");
    response = builder.build();
    return response;
}
```

This is my angularjs for getting image

```
var userImagePromise = $http.get("../api/s3/" + $scope.user.profileImage[0].id);
userImagePromise.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.imageData = data;
});
userImagePromise.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
});
```

This is my html for displaying image

```
<img id="userProfileImg" height="150px" width="150px" ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{imageData}}">
```

if I simply put the link to browser that image is downloaded
But in angular its not working why?

I alert that data it shows like this

�PNG
.\?.

How to display image in html?Any error in my code wise?

Comment: change this `ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{imageData}}" ` to `ng-src="{{imageData,'data:image/png;base64,'+imageData}}"`

Comment: @Hardik its not working can you help me.

Comment: Can you inspect in browser ?

Comment: I put ng-src="{{imageData,'data:image/png;base64,'+imageData}}" it shows error in browser

Comment: Revert back and what does that show in browser ?

Comment: if i put directly http://localhost:8080/sample/api/s3/580056y6666 in address bar that image is downloaded

Comment: Have Teamviewer

Comment: 404 error in that portion

Comment: did you tried manually pasting base64 string in place  ?

Comment: yes i patsed its working

Comment: Actually this one is correct Ji ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{imageData}

Comment: Yeah its correct too. may be you should prepare whole src and then assign it.

Comment: Actualli  I pasted the response data in brwser console its working fine

Comment: You might be replacing only the string. I am asking to prepare while string with `data:image/png;base64,` and server response then from controller assign it.

Comment: the problem is my imageData i think it contains ?PNG some  unwanted symbols etc is it correct

Comment: I alert that imageData it contains not like base64 string,but in browser console in resonse tab i got crrect string and i pasted it like this way its work fine <img src="data:image/gif;base64,IVF65757577...."/>

Comment: when you alert that it shows same output?

Comment: Content Type is Octect stream

Comment: @Hardik Can you help me

Comment: can you create a plunker or fiddle so that i can take a look ?

Comment: you have teamviwer

Comment: @Hardik actually that data is coming from mongodb chunks how it will create

Comment: its simple error only in morning onwards i am in screwed ji thats why i am asking

Comment: I can't connect TV, at work. Create a variable and place it in place of `{{imageData}}`.

Comment: its an octect steam how can i copy

Comment: its like this characcetr �PNG

Comment: may be you should stringify first.

Comment: Yes i stringify alert(JSON.stringify(data))

Comment: try giving `{{imageData}}` a stringified data.

Comment: I checked that too Ji i pasted {{imageData}} in my html page but its not printed nothing

Comment: give me your mail id i will post you

Comment: hpvaghani@yahoo.com